# Optimal Growing Conditions concerning CO2 level (ppm) for aquatic plants

Tags: botany

I know this is rather specific but I would like to know what level of CO2 concentration in the water is optimal for the highest possible plant growth rate.

I did an experiment where the growth rate increased with higher CO2 levels in the water of the plants. The highest ppm were 60 but I don't know if higher levels would keep increasing plant growth or decline due to high acidity of the water.

The specific plant if this helps would be *limnophila sessiliflora*

Any information on this would be much appreciated.

Jonas

Comment: have you tried Google Scholar yet ... ? it looks like some plants also use HCO3- ... https://nph.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1469-8137.1981.tb03198.x